# How can I accept virtual box license agreement in Ubuntu(16.04) terminal?

Tags: command-line, 13.04, 16.04, execute-command, license

[image]

I am new to Ubuntu. I have just installed Ubuntu-16.04 in virtual-box and my host-OS in windows-8.1. I have run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Comment: You can use the [`--accept-license` parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811488/command-to-accept-virtualbox-puel-for-virtualbox-ext-pack-installation/970246#970246) to avoid the question when you perform the installation at the command line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This you can do by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> once which should then highlight the `Ok` then press <kbd>return</kbd>. You might have to scroll down through the whole text to make it work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, if the answer solved your problem you can accept it by clicking the checkmark beside it.